# how to set up a cronjob to run 5 times every other wednesday?

Tags: php, cron

I have the need of running a script 5 times every other wednesday.
What further complicates it, is that the script needs to have a pause of atleast 1 hour between each run, 1 hour 10 minutes would be good.

I need this pause because its a newsletter sender, it sends alot of emails, and the mail-limit of the server is 3000 emails every hour.

So examples of when the script should run:

```
Wednesday February 20th at 10.00, 11.10, 12.20, 13.30, 14.40.
Wednesday March 6th at 10.00, 11.10, 12.20, 13.30, 14.40.
Wednesday March 20th at 10.00, 11.10, 12.20, 13.30, 14.40.
Wednesday April 3th at 10.00, 11.10, 12.20, 13.30, 14.40.
```

and so on.

Is it possible at all, or should i solve it some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sending logic (scheduling, throttling etc.) should really be handled in the application itself, and not via cron. If you move the logic to the application, you can setup a cronjob to run your app script every 10 minutes and it will only send the emails when the time is appropriate and the the application tells it to send.

Comment: i guess that would be the right way to do it. i were just hesitant to setting up a cronjob that runs 2000 times every 2 weeks without doing anything, it seems abit weird to me. but i guess thats the way.

Comment: @Kristian Rafteseth Ehhh....I'm actually not quite sure that I agree with this. Personally, I would abstract the sending mechanism from the application - if you're generating emails, you only need to create them and queue them. Whatever email handler you use should be responsible for the scheduling, throttling, etc. (That said, `cron` wouldn't be my choice for your specific use case.) You might try writing emails to a named pipe or something, and have the email handler read from that?

Answer (score 0):

The datetime class in PHP can be used to fetch days and complex timestamp combinations too. You can use a loop that counts through all the future days. That way you can index the wednesdays and use an offset-counter to define the delays of how many weeks and/or time you want it to execute.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

here is a guide to managing crons using php: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

basically your cron will take the form:

```
Minutes [0-59]  
|   Hours [0-23]  
|   |   Days [1-31]  
|   |   |   Months [1-12]  
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]  
|   |   |   |   |  
1   2   3   4   5 home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

You may need seperate jobs to run the pattern you need, or alternatively run the job every 10 minutes and let your script determine if the date/time is right